# ftp_connect() still undefined after uncommenting 'extension=php_ftp.dll' and restarting IIS

Tags: php, iis, printing, ftp

I've been trying to connect to a network printer using PHP on an IIS server, and it seems the FTP functions would be the best way to do this?

I am getting "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ftp_connect()".

This is after ensuring php_ftp.dll is in the ext folder, and is uncommented in php.ini. I also restarted IIS and the function is still undefined.

Is there anything else that can be done or a better way to do this?

Comment: are there any errors in the php error log? how does the line in the `php.ini` look like? And which version of php?

Comment: extension=php_ftp.dll with PHP version 7, Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ftp_connect() in...

Comment: check your `extension_dir` setting in the `php.ini` if your `php_ftp.dll` is inside the extension dir, try `extension=php_ftp` as the dll should be loaded by default. If it's not inside the extension dir, provide the full path to the dll

Comment: It doesn't seem to be making a difference, also when I do 'php --ri ftp' I get FTP support => enabled and
FTPS support => enabled